# AJAX & JQUERY when accessing database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Good day!

I have a problem when using AJAX & JQUERY when accessing my database.
After searching from the internet this script (I think) fit on my problem. I tried to mimic it but failed. [Using JQuery AJAX and php to fetch data from a mysql database](https://openenergymonitor.org/forum-archive/node/107.html)

my code:
userValidation.php

```
include '..\assets\database\connect.php';
$userLN = $_GET['userLN'];
$userFN = $_GET['userFN'];
// $userMN = $_GET['userMN'];
$regStatus='';

$i=0;
$getInfo = array();
$valLN=$valFN=$valMN='';
$query = "SELECT studLastname, studFirstname, studMiddlename FROM tblstudentinfo ";
$query .= "WHERE studLastname=? AND studFirstname=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$userLN,$userFN);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    $regStatus='exist';
}else{
    $regStatus='not exist';
}
echo json_encode($regStatus);
```

index.php

```
$('#btnNext').click(function() {
    var regStatus='';
    var urlParam='';
    var LN = document.getElementById('studRegLN').value;
    var FN = document.getElementById('studRegFN').value;
    urlParam="userLN="+LN+"&userFN="+FN;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/userValidation.php',
      data: urlParam,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data)
      {
        regStatus=data;
        alert(regStatus);
      }
    });
  });
```

My Scenario:
When an admin user register a Student Assistant it will input the last name and first name. when the next button clicked before accessing the next part of the page it will validate first if the S.A(student Assistant) is already exist.

so there are `$regStatus` & `var regStatus` variable... i want to use alert(); just to test if the variable was passed from $regStatus to regStatus(java variable).

BUT if you have better way to do this, then feel free to post your recommendations + code. Thank you

**UPDATE**
these are my screenshot that proves the codes is not working
[image]
[image]

notice the next button... I just clicked that but no `alert(getStatus)` pop-up

Comment: add type:"GET", in your ajax and try
Also add alert in the success of ajax

Comment: shame on me but where will I put the get? I review the w3school site but it's lacking of example in jquery-ajax get/post

Comment: below data: urlParam, add type:"GET"

Comment: let me if it's not worked

Comment: like this one? `type: 'get'`,

Comment: Yes but add  Capital 'GET'

Comment: didn't work... I just update my post... I added your suggested code... the `alert(regStatus)` is still empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164741/discussion-between-priyank-and-mark).

Comment: @Priyank GET is the default if not specified, and "type" is the legacy option - "method" should be used unless OP's version of jQuery is ancient. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for documentation of both of those facts

Comment: @Mark "didn't work" means what? What errors / unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Yes @ADyson but some time it creates problem that's why i mentioned.

Comment: @Priyank evidence please? If you don't specify it, it defaults to get. Therefore your suggestion makes no functional difference to the OP's code.

Comment: @Mark why have you wrapped the ajax call in `$(function()
    {` - the execution is already delayed until the button is clicked, so you don't need to wait until the document is ready (which is what this code would do)

Comment: @Mark ajax calls are asynchronous, so put your alert inside the "success" function as Priyank suggested, if you want to see the updated value of regStatus. Otherwise the alert runs before the ajax call is complete, so you won't see the updated value

Comment: @ADyson didn't work it means the value of regStatus is empty, if I put the `alert(getStatus)` inside success no alert pop-up showed.

Comment: @Mark remove the `$(function() {` and the matching `});` as I suggested and then try again. Watch your browser's Console and Network tools to see if the ajax request actually gets made, and what the response is, if any.

Comment: @ADyson just updated my post.. still didn't work

Comment: The error in your console is coming from somewhere else, not from this code. Click on the line number to go to the relevant bit of code. I guess it's some sort of validation routine containing a regular expression. Probably you just need to remove the space before the `]` in the expression.

Comment: it's only a `pattern=` for html5... I just erase those code from my input still nothing happen... no alert pop-up

Comment: @ADyson it work! but I don't know why! why is it that when I input `sdfsdfsdfs` it says 'not exist' but when I input existed Last name and First name the `exist` is not showing?

Comment: You'd have to debug your PHP and find out. Perhaps it crashes. You don't check for SQL errors anywhere. Try my code below which will output the response from the server in the case where there's an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handful of problems:

1) not URL-encoding your querystring parameter values, especially since they're names and might easily contain characters not permitted on a querystring. Let jQuery handle this for you by passing an object as the "data". N.B. You could also consider sending this request as  POST, then the values will be in the request body, and cannot cause problems on your querystring.

2) It's not clear whether you wait until the document is fully loaded before you declare your "click" event handler. In an earlier revision of the question you had a document.ready block *inside* the click handler, which made no sense. If you haven't already, wrap your button click code inside a document.ready handler, to ensure that your button already exists in the DOM by the time you try to bind to it. Also ensure you used the correct ID selector - I can't see your HTML so can't check that for you.

3) Ajax calls are asynchronous, so put your alert inside the "success" function as Priyank suggested, if you want to see the updated value of regStatus. Otherwise the alert runs before the ajax call is complete, so you won't see the updated value

4) It's not clear what type of button you've used (again, the HTML is missing from your question), but if it's a submit type, then it will post back the page simultaneously unless you explicitly prevent that in your JS code. If it posts back, then the page is destroyed and your ajax request will either not run, or the response from it will be be lost because the page it ran from is destroyed.

Putting these all together should result in something like this:

```
$(function() { //don't declare click handler until document is fully ready and all HTML elements are loaded.
  $('#btnNext').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default button postback behaviour, if any
    var regStatus='';
    var LN = document.getElementById('studRegLN').value;
    var FN = document.getElementById('studRegFN').value;

    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/userValidation.php',
      data: { //let jQuery do the URL-encoding for you
            "userLN": LN,
            "userFN": FN
      },
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data)
      {
        regStatus = data;
        alert(regStatus); //alert must be in here to definitely delay executing the alert until the variable is populated from the asynchronous server response
      },
      error: function(jqXHR) { //handle ajax errors
        alert("Error: " + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: the codes work like your other suggestions but this it didn't work... 1st when I put the jquery url-coding and alert code did'nt show up... but if I stick to my first code it's work... btw the `echo '<div>....'` on my uservalidation.php is the cause why my alert did't work...

Comment: I don't see `echo '<div>....' ` in your PHP code above, otherwise I would have mentioned it. But yes that would explain it, because it means the response is not valid JSON, so jQuery is unable to parse it according to the `dataType: "json"` directive.

Comment: Odd that the urlEncoding doesn't work, it should make it more robust. Are you sure you followed my example correctly? Again, check your ajax request in the browser tools to see what is actually being submitted in that instance, and how it differs from your version. When I tested my version, it would make a URL like `ajax/userValidation.php?userLn=kjkjdfg&userFn=dfgjhdfkjg` which seems fine

Comment: ok I will try again your code.. by the way I didn't include the `$(function() { ` the last time I tried your code

Comment: actually I spotted my mistake - should be "userLN" and "userFN" - php is case-sensitive to the variable names. I have edited the answer. The use or otherwise of `$(function() {` would not directly affect this specific problem.

Comment: oh! I also didn't notice the `userLn`.. now your code worked and as you said it must be j-query will do the url-encoding.. thanks man!

Comment: Yes. This method is safer than the previously accepted answer because it won't break the URL if the submitted values contain any special characters

Comment: last comment.. by the way about `button` I used `type="button"` because I started to convert all my projects to AJAX.. I noticed that all the query is more x10 faster than my previous code.. like loading 5k records it takes 1 minute to load.. but when I convert my code to AJAX it takes only seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Change your ajax with this one.**

```
$('#btnNext').click(function() {
        var regStatus='';
        var urlParam='';
        var LN = document.getElementById('studRegLN').value;
        var FN = document.getElementById('studRegFN').value;
        urlParam="userLN="+LN+"&userFN="+FN;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/userValidation.php',
            data: urlParam,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
              regStatus=data;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: didn't work... plus the `alert(getStatus)` inside `success: function(data){
              regStatus=data;alert(regStatus);
            }` when I put the code inside that success

Comment: Did you get any error in console ? If yes then mentione here.
Also did you include Jquery library in your index.php page ?

Comment: it worked now.. the problem why your code didn't work because of the echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">....';` inside `if($stmt->num_rows > 0){`. If I delete that line of code.. the word `exist` will showed in the pop-up.. thanks man

Comment: please verify my answer

Comment: it will break if the user enters any special characters into either of the fields. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent for lists of acceptable and problematic characters. As per my answer, jQuery can be employed to take care of this, or you can manually call encodeURIComponent on each field.

Answer (score -1):

Ajax Call Should be like.

```
    var lanme=document.getElementById('studRegLN').value;
    var fname=document.getElementById('studRegFN').value;
    $.ajax({
     url: 'ajax/userValidation.php',
     type:'GET', /* GET or POST */     
     data: {
            userLn:lname,
            userFn:fname
            },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data)
     {
       regStatus=data;
     }
    });
```

Hey, i'm new to Stack overflow Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Hi! welcome to stackoverflow:-) sad to say your code didn't work.. I can't show the value for `alert(regStatus)` it's either  'exist' or 'not exist' these are the value I want to get because I will put that variable in 'if' conditions

Comment: PHP is case-sensitive about the variable names, so userLn must be UserLN and same for the other one. And also you forgot the alert. And your comment - GET or POST are not interchangeable when the server is expecting GET

Comment: yes @ADyson ! case-sensitive is by mistict and /*get or post */ use for info. don't take it wrong.